# MySQL get list of dates and join with another tab

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I'm trying to generate seven rows for each date in the last seven days, and join with a query from `transactions` table. The aim is to have a table with each date, and the cumulative total of the `quantity` column in `transactions` from the first entry up to the date:

```
|      date     |  stockOnDate  |
|---------------|---------------|
| 2021-10-15    | 10            |
| 2021-10-16    | 3             |
| 2021-10-17    | 0             |
| 2021-10-18    | 9             |
| 2021-10-19    | 15            |
| 2021-10-20    | 15            |
| 2021-10-21    | 15            |
```

I can get the list of dates, and can join, but can't filter the nested queries:

```sql
SELECT v.*, t.* 
FROM ( SELECT DATE(ADDDATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 7 DAY), t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0)) AS `date` 
       FROM (SELECT 0 t0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t0,
            (SELECT 0 t1 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t1,
            (SELECT 0 t2 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t2,
            (SELECT 0 t3 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t3 ) AS v
LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(quantity) AS stockOnDate, DATE(timestamp) as tDate 
           FROM `transactions` 
           WHERE tDate <= v.`date`) AS t ON t.tDate = v.`date`
WHERE v.`date` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND v.`date` <= DATE(NOW())
```

But I'm receviing the following error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'tDate' in 'where clause'
```

If I replace `WHERE tDate <= v.date` with `WHERE DATE(timestamp) <= v.date` I get the same error for v.date - I can't seem to access the value of the parent tables.

I'm not great with MySQL but can't seem to find a solution, where am I going wrong?

## Solution by ProGuru

Thanks to [ProGuru's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69659408/2153993), the below query works as expected (using `<=` instead of `=` in the `JOIN` was key)

```
SELECT b.date, SUM(a.quantity) AS stockOnDate
FROM (
 SELECT DATE(ADDDATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 6 DAY), t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0)) AS `date` 
       FROM (SELECT 0 t0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t0,
            (SELECT 0 t1 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t1,
            (SELECT 0 t2 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t2,
            (SELECT 0 t3 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t3
) b 
LEFT JOIN transactions a ON DATE(a.timestamp) <= b.date
WHERE b.date BETWEEN DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 6 DAY AND DATE(NOW())
AND a.organisationId = 1
GROUP BY b.date
ORDER BY b.date ASC
```

I can also change the `GROUP BY` to `GROUP BY a.itemID, b.date` to get the stock level on the given date for each itemId.

Comment: *```.. WHERE tDate <= v.`date` ..```* You cannot use output column alias (tDate) in WHERE. Either use its expression (`DATE(timestamp)`) instead or apply this condition in HAVING. Also you cannot refer to subquery column from another subquery (v.date) until LATERAL is specified.

Comment: What is your MySQL precise version? Also I recommend you to create online fiddle with sample data and to provide desired output with detailed explanations. Of course, for more short data range...

Comment: Same result with `HAVIING` unfortunately, as I said using `DATE(timestamp` leads to same issue with `v.date`. Using 10.4.19-MariaDB, the desired result is at the start of the post

Comment: *Same result with HAVIING unfortunately* I predict this - "Also you cannot refer to subquery column from another subquery (v.date) until LATERAL is specified." *Using 10.4.19-MariaDB* For this version your query should be completely rewrited - use sequence or recursive CTE for dates list generation and window function for cumulative sum calculation.

Comment: *the desired result is at the start of the post* Do you think that desired output without source data may make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the cumulative sum of quantity, the date join needs to use `<=`

Revised SQL

```
SELECT b.date, SUM(COALESCE(a.quantity, 0))
FROM (
 SELECT DATE(ADDDATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 7 DAY), t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0)) AS `date` 
       FROM (SELECT 0 t0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t0,
            (SELECT 0 t1 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t1,
            (SELECT 0 t2 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t2,
            (SELECT 0 t3 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t3
) b 
LEFT JOIN transactions a ON DATE(a.timestamp) <= b.date
WHERE b.date BETWEEN DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 6 DAY AND DATE(NOW())
GROUP BY b.date
ORDER BY b.date ASC
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=34f78e3d7c9225727ac2e728588759e2

Comment: This has done the trick - never knew you could join using a <= operator. I've even managed to add a second group by to get the stock level for each item (in transactions) by date. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To use alias in where clause, you must encapsulate your query in another select.

Example :

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT SUM(quantity) AS stockOnDate, DATE(timestamp) as tDate FROM `transactions`) seb
WHERE seb.tDate <= v.`date`
```

Update try this:

```
SELECT v.*, t.* 
FROM ( SELECT DATE(ADDDATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 7 DAY), t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0)) AS `date` 
       FROM (SELECT 0 t0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t0,
            (SELECT 0 t1 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t1,
            (SELECT 0 t2 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t2,
            (SELECT 0 t3 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t3 ) AS v
LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(quantity) AS stockOnDate, DATE(timestamp) as tDate FROM transactions) AS t ON t.tDate = v.`date`
WHERE t.tDate <= v.`date` and v.`date` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND v.`date` <= DATE(NOW())
```

here tDate can be used

Comment: indeed. Updated.

Comment: Assuming I've done what you meant right, I'm still getting the same error `#1054 - Unknown column 'v.date' in 'where clause'` using `LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT SUM(quantity) AS stockOnDate, DATE(timestamp) as tDate FROM `transactions`) seb WHERE seb.tDate <= v.date) t ON t.tDate = v.date`

Comment: v.date cannot be referenced here, it must placed out of the query (WHERE seb.tDate <= v.`date` and v.`date` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND v.`date` <= DATE(NOW()))

Comment: check my answer (update)

Comment: OP needs in cumulative sum in `t` subquery.

Comment: Thanks but that returns 0 rows (no errors though!) - I need a cumulative sum so as understand it `t.date <= v.date` needs to be in the subquery to make sure it only SUMs up to the current row's `v.date`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to understand that in this subquery

```
(SELECT SUM(quantity) AS stockOnDate, DATE(timestamp) as tDate 
           FROM `transactions` 
           WHERE tDate <= v.`date`) AS t
```

there is nothing defined as `date` or even the alias `v`. You're basically telling the query to look for `v.date` when it doesn't exists in the subquery.

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT dt, IFNULL(SUM(quantity),0) AS stockOnDate
    FROM (SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(LEFT(NOW(),7),LPAD(seq,2,0)), '%Y-%m%d') dt
             FROM seq_1_to_31) v
        LEFT JOIN  `transactions` t ON dt=DATE(timestamp)
    WHERE dt >= (SELECT MIN(DATE(timestamp)) FROM `transactions`)
       AND dt <= (SELECT MAX(DATE(timestamp)) FROM `transactions`)
GROUP BY dt;
```

Here I'm using MariaDB's built-in [sequence engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sequence-storage-engine/) to generate days; concatenated with current year-month combination then uses `STR_TO_DATE` to make it recognizable as proper date format. The query generating those is in subquery `v`.

Second option is using a [recursive common table expression](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/) to generate the date range based on existing date data in the table. Here is the query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
SELECT MIN(DATE(timestamp)) mndt, MAX(DATE(timestamp)) mxdt FROM `transactions`
UNION ALL
SELECT mndt+INTERVAL 1 DAY, mxdt FROM cte WHERE mndt+INTERVAL 1 DAY <= mxdt)
SELECT mndt, IFNULL(SUM(quantity),0) AS stockOnDate
    FROM cte
        LEFT JOIN  `transactions` t ON mndt=DATE(timestamp)
GROUP BY mndt;
```

Both the query above eliminates the need to include a long subquery that generates the date range. This is the benefit of newer MySQL & MariaDB versions.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=1f397bf725dad4a103ff930ab5d54666)